# How do I change current retropie to a ready to play img?

Tags: retropie, image

I was wondering if I wanted to change my current running retropie to another retropie img do I just remove the micro sd card and pop in another one with a different img

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my opinion that's one of the best features of the Raspberry Pi.

Simply swap sd cards for whatever operating system or setup you fancy.

If you no longer want your original Retropie image you could re-flash that sd card with the new image.

Comment: Yes. The Pi is just hardware with no special locking to any OS. Everything gets bootstrapped from the DOS FAT partition so as long as the OS supports the hardware you can boot it. Like Windows IoT, Ubuntu Mate, RiscOS, etc etc. Whatever is on the Card. You can even put several OS's on the card and have a grub menu select which one you want. (more advanced though)